# Receive and TC-redirect traffic with any VLAN tag

Tags: linux, networking, vlan

I have an interface `eth0`, from which I want to mirror all incoming traffic to, say, `eth1`, so I use the following commands:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 handle ffff: ingress
tc filter add dev eth0 parent ffff: prio 1 u32 match u32 0 0 action mirred ingress mirror dev eth1
```

It works perfectly with everything except VLAN-tagged packets - they can be seen in Wireshark on `eth0`, but they do not appear on `eth1`. If I do:

```
vconfig add eth0 $TAG
```

Where `$TAG` is some tag from my input traffic, the corresponding packets start to appear on `eth1`.

But, as I have written, I want to capture *all* incoming traffic, and that means I want to capture all VLAN tags as well. I'm pretty sure it will work if I add all tags from 2 up to 4094, creating all those sub-interfaces, but I wonder if there is some smarter way to do so? Also, I'm concerned about performance issues, which may appear when having so much interfaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After researching more I have discovered that the utility `bridge`, which is part of `iproute2` collection, can be used to solve this issue. I have no idea why the following approach works, but you can try to do the same if you have a similar problem.

So, suppose we already have the setup I described earlier (without `vconfig`-adding the VLAN tags), then do:

```
ip link add bridge_dev type bridge
ip link set bridge_dev up
ip link set eth0 master bridge_dev
```

These commands create a bridge device, turn it on and set `eth0` device as a slave of the `bridge_dev`. Right after the last command I start seeing the VLAN-tagged packets on `eth1`, as expected.

Note that you can also add VLAN tags to bridge devices, like:

```
bridge vlan add vid 2-4094 dev bridge_dev self
```

I expected to only see VLAN packets after that command, but apparently it's not necessary. I would welcome anyone who could explain, why this works.